# Analysis Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Need some help here. I'm really new into this. I had to miss the first lesson of the first week because I wasn't enrolled in yet and the prof covered quite some material. I have no friends to ask to :/

What are the best and worst run-times of the algorithm below? Notice there are 2 parameters
N and M.

```
int a[N] = { .... }; // initialized with DISTINCT random numbers
                     //ranging from 0 to M
int hash[M] = { 0 }; // init all M elements to 0
std::sort( a, a+N ); // assume O( N log N ) time

for ( int i=0; i<M; ++i ) { // notice 0 .. M-1 loop
    hash[ i ] = 1;
    if ( i > a[N-1] ) break; // a[N-1] is maximum element, so we are done
}
```

I'm stuck on this question my prof gave my class as a homework and I'm totally clueless on this.

Comment: Course notes/textbook/fellow students really is going to be more valuable to find that any help we can offer here. If we give you an anwer, will you *understand it*? If not, how can you verify that we've given you a useful answer?

Comment: Here's my attempt.
     `Best run-time: O(N log N)`
     `Worst run-time: O(N+(N log N))`

Comment: [edit] your question with these thoughts, and explain *how you reached these conclusions*. We're happy to help most people here but where it's homework, we're more generally favourable to questions where we can see your existing work and thinking and *steer* you in the right direction rather than just handing you an answer.

Comment: For my best run-time; since it's already doing the sort which is O(N log N) and assuming the if stmt is true at some point(which will run until some i-value, a constant which is negligible) we set it to O(N log N).

For Worst run-time, the for-loop is assumed will run until N since we don't know the value of M, therefore its just an addition with the sort algorithm: O(N+(N logN))

Comment: Ask yourself what happens when the sorted array contains `[1,3,9,12]` and `M == 13`. At what point is `i > a[N-1]`? Does that change your worst case running time? What about your best case running time?

Comment: So the worst case running time would be O(M+ (N log N)). The content of a[N] contains random numbers ranging from 0 to M. So in order for the if stmt to be true, 'i' has to be more than the value 'M' or 'M-1' (just choose M cuz '1' is small), so it has to iterate till i == M. As for the best case running time, I would not change it I guess. If the content of array a[N] has the number 1 on it, the for loop will break straight. Correct me if I'm wrong...